# Error when updating the scan period with Android beacon Library

Tags: ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I am trying to change the scan period with android beacon library. This is my code

```
 BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
        beaconManager.bind(this);

        try {
            beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(50l); // 1100 mS
            beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(0l); // 0ms
            beaconManager.updateScanPeriods();
        }
        catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
        }
```

I tried different devices but I always get this error
 The BeaconManager is not bound to the service.  Call beaconManager.bind(BeaconConsumer consumer) and wait for a callback to onBeaconServiceConnect()

I think the value of the scan period changes even if I get this error but I am not sure

Comment: Which line throws this error?

Comment: the try/catch  Log.e("error", e.getMessage());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call `beaconManager.updateScanPeriods();` until *after* you get the callback to `onBeaconServiceConnect()` otherwise you get the error mentioned in the question.  Understand that the call to `bind()` stats up the beacon scanning service, which is not instantaneous.  When you make the call to update the scan periods, it will fail if the service is not started up yet -- it takes a second or two.

Two options:

- Move the code to set the scan periods inside `onBeaconServiceConnect()`.
- Move the code that sets the foreground and background scan periods before the call to `bind()` and then remove the `beaconManager.updateScanPeriods();` line.  If you set the scan periods before calling bind, they will automatically be applied when the service starts up.